# Flutter, testing future that throws an Error makes the test unloadable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to run a flutter test where a `widget` displays an error page when the `Future` provided to it throws an error (via `FutureBuilder`).

However the line where I create the future seems to be making the test fail.

```
final futureError = Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 20))
    .then((value) => throw Error());
```

with the message

```
 Failed to load "D:\Projects\flutter\....dart": Instance of 'Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it inside the test function resolved the issue

```
testWidgets('...',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
     await tester.runAsync(() async {
          final futureError = Future.error('error');
          // ...
```

(it was in the group method prior to this)